# how to sum each specific rendered row horizontally on jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, yajra-datatable

I get data for datasrc from sql query and I display for each column using

```
"data": "attribute", "name": "name",
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {}
```

I can't get calculate value from sql query, I have to get  each rendred  value of specific row to sum and put the result in each column horizontally
exemple bellow of eachrow :  row 1 col1 + row 1 col2 + row 1 col3 and put te result in row 1 col4

and the same for all horizontal ligne.

```
Rows                  Col1        Col2      Col3    Col4  col5      col6      col7 
1                      12         1         23       36    string    string   string
2                       1         0          5       6     string    
3                       6         2          9       16    string
```

for this jquery datatable serverside Showing 1-10:

```
"autoWidth": true,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                'type': 'POST',
                'url': 
                'dataSrc':function (json) {
                   

                    return json.data;
                },
                'complete': function (response) {
                   
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                {"data": "id"},
               {"data": "attribute", "name": "name",
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {}
}
                    ---
                  ---
```

Comment: Are you unable to update the SQL Query? It would be much faster to do in SQL.For DataTables, the topic example is here: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html

Comment: Yes it's faster in SQL query, but in my case it's not possible because from data SQL I do much calcul that need data over database.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following snippet.

```
"columns": [{
  "data": "id"
},
{
  "data": "attribute",
  "name": "name",
  "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
    return (row[1] + row[2] + row[3]);
  },
  "targets": 4
}]
```

See More: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

Comment: For this approach the row return value from dataSource but I look for value rendered, thx for your answer.